# query to fetch the number of rows fetched by another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I fetch the number of rows fetched by another query in SQL server:

The required value should be:

```
select count(*) of select * from table
```

Comment: `select count(*) FROM (select * from table) AS tmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(
 select * from yourtable
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this Query for the number of rows fetched by another query in SQL server

```
select temp.TblCount From
(select Count(*) As TblCount from YOURTABLE) As Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the nested query? If all you need is the count of rows fetched by a query, better replace everything in the SELECT clause of that query with 'SELECT COUNT(*)' thus saving on using nested queries

**Query 1:**

```
select COUNT(*) from 
(
    select col1, col2, col3
    From Table1
    WHERE <Conditions>
)as x
```

**Query 2:**

```
select COUNT(*)
From Table1
WHERE <Conditions>
```

Both the Queries should be giving the same Output.